# how to get thumbnail url with Dailymotion api just after a video is uploaded

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am trying to retrieve “thumbnail_url” with using API after I just uploaded a video.
However, “thumbnail_url” I retrieved is always this URL “Hhttp://s2.dmcdn.net/KtV-L.jpg” or “Hhttp://s2.dmcdn.net/KtV-L/x240-gK0.jpg” (when I used oEmbed API).

On the other hand, I am able to get “thumbnail_url”that I wanted when I put the URL into the address bar in the browser manually like following URL.
Hhttps://api.dailymotion.com/video/VIDEOID?fields=thumbnail_url

My question is;
Is there time lag or does Dailymotion API need more time to generate a thumbnail image just after a video is uploaded?
Or, is the way to retrieve the thumbnail url I coded wrong?

Here is the code to get thumbnail image url.
*As a prerequisite, I already got access token, created a video and published.

```
///////////////   Publish a video   ///////////////

    $publishVideoAPI = "https://api.dailymotion.com/video/".$responseID;
    // Post data
    $dataPublish = array(
    "title" => $videotitle,
    "published" => true,
    "channel" => "shortfilms",
    "tags" => $tags,
    "access_token" => $accesstoken
    );
    $conn = curl_init();
    // Post method
    curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_URL, $publishVideoAPI);
    curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataPublish);

    // execute
    $resPublish = curl_exec($conn);
echo "publish video<br />";
    var_dump($resPublish);
    // close
    curl_close($conn);


///////////////   Grab a thumbnail image of the video start   ///////////////

    // API
    $thumbnail = "https://api.dailymotion.com/video/".$responseID."?fields=thumbnail_url";

    // initialise session
    $conn = curl_init();

    // Get method
    curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_URL, $thumbnail);

    // execute
    $res2 = curl_exec($conn);
echo "thumbnail url<br />";
    //var_dump($res2);
echo "<br /><br />";
    // close
    curl_close($conn);

$thumbnailData = json_decode( $res2 , true );
$thumbnailURL = $thumbnailData["thumbnail_url"];
echo $thumbnailURL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have all ready execute this code
GET Method this url :    https://api.dailymotion.com/video/'+videoID+'?fields=id,thumbnail_url,thumbnail_120_url

Than find response :

{"id":"x2qwonn","thumbnail_url":"http://s2.dmcdn.net/Kra86.jpg","thumbnail_120_url":"http://s2.dmcdn.net/Kra86/x120-aNB.jpg"}

response = {"id":"x2qwonn","thumbnail_url":"http://s2.dmcdn.net/Kra86.jpg","thumbnail_120_url":"http://s2.dmcdn.net/Kra86/x120-aNB.jpg"}

thumbnail = response['thumbnail_120_url'].replace("\","")

get result

http://s2.dmcdn.net/Kra86/x120-aNB.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response.
I figured this out and now uploaded the thumbnail image properly.
As you tested, this code was right.
The reason that the image I uploaded was always same image provided by Dailymotion was that the video status was "processing".
So I put the loop to check the status with 10 seconds interval, and only when the status turned to "published", try to grab the thumbnail image.